# Android Segmentation fault Tombstone debug 6.0.1, 6.0.0

Tags: android, tombstone

Steps to take to try and debug this will be greatly appreciated. 
The bug only happens on android 6.0.0 and android 6.0.1, at random times so my only hope is to try to debug the app.
My code is written entirely in native Android Java.

05-10 10:31:15.471 15933-15933/com.ragemods A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 15933 (com.ragemods)

and here is the tombstone that goes along with it:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/svwhdzub70klgpb/tombstone_00?dl=0

Thanks for your help.

Also incase this is helpful here is my entrie stack trace:

```
05-10 10:28:25.057 15933-15933/com.ragemods W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ragemods-1/lib/arm
05-10 10:28:25.136 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/Rage: Rage: on create called
05-10 10:28:25.157 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/Rage: Rage: app context null
05-10 10:28:25.157 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/Rage: Rage: on create view null
05-10 10:28:25.324 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.398 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.443 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.492 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.537 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.592 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.650 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.716 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.772 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.808 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.858 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.907 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.931 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.953 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.965 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:25.986 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.014 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.062 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.085 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.119 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.150 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.194 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.224 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.249 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.286 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.332 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.378 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.432 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.495 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.540 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.562 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.588 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.614 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.646 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.685 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.732 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.778 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.801 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.838 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.895 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.935 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:26.974 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:27.013 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:27.057 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:27.093 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:27.123 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:27.147 15933-15933/com.ragemods D/MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
05-10 10:28:27.535 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/!!!!!!load!!!!!: loaddone
05-10 10:28:27.542 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/Rage: Rage: on resume called
05-10 10:28:27.549 15933-16163/com.ragemods D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-10 10:28:27.610 15933-16163/com.ragemods I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
05-10 10:28:27.613 15933-16163/com.ragemods I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-10 10:28:28.605 15933-16162/com.ragemods V/rage spawn people: Rage spawn people Took 1.0590515 seconds
05-10 10:28:30.643 15933-16162/com.ragemods V/rage spawn cars: Rage spawn cars Took 1.34906 seconds
05-10 10:28:33.595 15933-15940/com.ragemods W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.141ms
05-10 10:28:43.697 15933-15940/com.ragemods W/art: Suspending all threads took: 35.125ms
05-10 10:28:44.672 15933-15940/com.ragemods W/art: Suspending all threads took: 7.293ms
05-10 10:29:02.807 15933-15940/com.ragemods W/art: Suspending all threads took: 45.379ms
05-10 10:29:13.527 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/rage spawn people: Rage spawn people Took 0.8362427 seconds
05-10 10:29:14.905 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/rage spawn cars: Rage spawn cars Took 0.8807373 seconds
05-10 10:29:14.912 15933-15933/com.ragemods I/Choreographer: Skipped 133 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-10 10:29:36.407 15933-15940/com.ragemods W/art: Suspending all threads took: 15.502ms
05-10 10:29:51.115 15933-15933/com.ragemods E/MediaPlayer: internal/external state mismatch corrected
05-10 10:30:12.128 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/rage spawn people: Rage spawn people Took 0.8179322 seconds
05-10 10:30:13.507 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/rage spawn cars: Rage spawn cars Took 0.86376953 seconds
05-10 10:30:31.199 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/rage spawn people: Rage spawn people Took 0.8010864 seconds
05-10 10:30:32.617 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/rage spawn cars: Rage spawn cars Took 0.9103699 seconds
05-10 10:30:32.621 15933-15933/com.ragemods I/Choreographer: Skipped 134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-10 10:30:46.152 15933-15940/com.ragemods W/art: Suspending all threads took: 22.155ms
05-10 10:30:53.682 15933-15944/com.ragemods I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 805761(15MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 33% free, 30MB/45MB, paused 671us total 153.503ms
05-10 10:30:57.850 15933-15989/com.ragemods W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.ragemods/lib
05-10 10:30:57.937 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/!!!!!!savedone!!!!!: savedone
05-10 10:30:57.939 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/Rage: Rage: on create called
05-10 10:30:57.942 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/Rage: Rage: app context null
05-10 10:30:57.942 15933-15933/com.ragemods V/Rage: Rage: on resume called
05-10 10:30:57.976 15933-16163/com.ragemods V/RenderScript: 0x9f0f5000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
05-10 10:31:01.753 15933-15940/com.ragemods W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.462ms
05-10 10:31:06.486 15933-15944/com.ragemods I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 912685(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 34% free, 29MB/45MB, paused 579us total 104.888ms
05-10 10:31:12.996 15933-15944/com.ragemods I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 860407(16MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 34% free, 30MB/45MB, paused 396us total 101.684ms
05-10 10:31:15.471 15933-15933/com.ragemods A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 15933 (com.ragemods)
```